# MySQL get subset of a select statement based on contents

Tags: mysql

I created a survey users could fill out.  Question 0 is the leading question, which has 4 choices.  Based on which option they choose, they get a different subset of questions.  IF they decide to, they can hit the browser back button to question 0 and pick a different subset.  This overwrites their Question 0 response, and their other survey questions are logged.  If a user was particularly naughty they could do all 11 questions, and so they have 1 record created for each possible question.

The problem is I need to report on the surveys.  If I do a straight sum of all Question 1 responses, it will include those people who have since changed their mind.  I need to do a select statement that takes into account their leading question and selects their survey set associated to that one.

Here's this fancy code I had made awhile ago, it makes a really nice SUM grid for all questions and answers.  Though it doesn't do what I am asking.

```
select distinct user_id, q_id, 

sum(IF(answer like '%A%',1,0)) as A, 
sum(IF(answer like '%B%',1,0)) as B, 
sum(IF(answer like '%C%',1,0)) as C, 
sum(IF(answer like '%D%',1,0)) as D,
sum(IF(answer like '%E%',1,0)) as E,
sum(IF(answer like '%F%',1,0)) as F

from user_answers as t1

join 
(   select distinct id
    from users
    WHERE stepflag = 4 //finished the survey
    and disq = 0
) inr

on inr.id=t1.user_id
group by q_id;
```

There is a users table and their IDs are logged into the answers table as user_id with respective responses.  I hope I've given enough info, thank you for the help

The above query result, but with bloated numbers because of the issue.  Also don't ask me how the one person entered 1 D.

[image: the result of the above query]

user_answers table

[image: user_answers]

And the users table is your standard id, fname, lname, disq, timestamp type table for collecting user data.

Comment: Can you show sample data and desired output?

Comment: It would be more useful to see the sample data set.

Comment: Thanks, I added some pictures

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out my question:

I'm bad at making complicated MySQL queries so I'll try to explain it if it helps someone else

```
select t1.q_id, 
   sum(t1.answer like '%A%') as A, 
   sum(t1.answer like '%B%') as B, 
   sum(t1.answer like '%C%') as C, 
   sum(t1.answer like '%D%') as D, 
   sum(t1.answer like '%E%') as E, 
   sum(t1.answer like '%F%') as F
from user_answers t1 join 
 (select distinct id, `date`
  from users
  where stepflag = 4 and 
    disq = 0
 ) inr
 on inr.id = t1.user_id join
 user_answers q0
 on q0.user_id = t1.user_id and q0.q_id = 0
where (q0.answer = 'A' and t1.q_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)) or
  (q0.answer = 'B' and t1.q_id in (5, 6, 7, 8)) or
  (q0.answer = 'C' and t1.q_id in (9, 10, 11)) 
group by t1.q_id;
```

I'm tallying up all the answers based on their varchar value.  Keep in mind this can be modified for multiple choice if you have many letters in one answer set, it just gets more complicated.

The magic's in the bottom portion.  The leading question's A value leads to survey set 1-4, B leads to 5-8, and C leads to 9-11.  D was an opt out so there's no associating survey set.

This query takes a long time to run, so if you got a big database you may have to extend the connection timeout.  I'm working with 20,000+ records and I eschewed timeouts by doing only one Q0 survey choice at a time